# The sum up of each row in Array in C language doesn't show correctly

Tags: c

This is the code I wrote, but instead of showing a total for each line, it shows:

line 1: sum of line 1 (this shows correctly)
line 2: sum of line 1 and line 2
line 3: sum of line 1 thru 3
line 4: sum of line 1 thru 4
line 5: sum of line 1 thru 5

Can someone tell me which part I did it wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define YEARS 5
#define MONTHS 12

int main() {
    int years;
    int months;
    int TotalYearlyRainfall = 0;
    int rain[YEARS][MONTHS] = {
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}
    };
    
    printf("Total Rainfall\n");
    
    for (years = 0; years < YEARS; years++) {
        for (months = 0; months < MONTHS; months++)
            TotalYearlyRainfall+=rain[years][months];
        
        printf("%i\n", TotalYearlyRainfall);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't describe the output. Just show it exactly. That is, give the exact expected output and actual output.

Comment: Also, `years`, `months`, and `TotalYearlyRainfall` can be locally scoped to your loops.

Comment: you need to reset your total rainfall variable. your code is currently added all the values up.

Comment: IMHO, I suggest that the variable's name ```TotalYearlyRainfall``` be changed to ```MonthlyRainfall```, because ```TotalYearlyRainfall``` is kind of misleading.

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize `TotalYearlyRainfall` to `0` at the start of each year.

After your first for loop, set:

```
TotalYearlyRainfall = 0;
```

Comment: Better yet would be to locally scope this variable to the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

The variable's name is `TotalYearlyRainfall`, which makes me think it should have the sum of all the twelve months. If you would like to have the sum of each month separately, I suggest that the variable's name be `MonthlyRainfall` or something similar.

The problem with the original code is that the variable `TotalYearlyRainfall` or `MonthlyRainfall` should be reset to zero after each inner for loop, because it acts as the counter of the sum of each month.

Remember to use this form : `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` to be standard compliant.

The following code is C89 compliant.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define YEARS 5
#define MONTHS 12

int main(void) {
    int years;
    int months;
    int MonthlyRainfall = 0;
    int rain[YEARS][MONTHS] = {
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}
    };
    
    printf("Total Rainfall\n");
    
    for (years = 0; years < YEARS; years++) {
        /* This variable should be reset to zero after each inner loop */
        MonthlyRainfall = 0; 
        for (months = 0; months < MONTHS; months++)
            MonthlyRainfall+=rain[years][months];
        
        printf("%i\n", MonthlyRainfall);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

At this time, C99 has been widely supported by compilers, maybe, you would like to consider the following code also.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define YEARS 5
#define MONTHS 12

int main(void) {
    int rain[YEARS][MONTHS] = {
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}
    };
    
    printf("Total Rainfall\n");
    
    for (int years = 0; years < YEARS; years++) {
        // This variable should be reset to zero after each inner loop
        int MonthlyRainfall = 0; 
        for (int months = 0; months < MONTHS; months++)
            MonthlyRainfall+=rain[years][months];
        
        printf("%i\n", MonthlyRainfall);
    }

    return 0;
}
```